# Difference from two set of nodes - XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a sample Xml like below. This has two Root Elements named "Param" and "Dimension".

Param Element is also having a child node named "Dimension", and it contains some elements named "Member". This has two attributes id and name.

```
<Root>  
    <Param>
        <Pattern id="P1" name="Pattern1">
            <Dimension name="Dim1">
                <Member id= "1" name="Member1" />
                <Member id= "4" name="Member4" />
                <Member id= "5" name="Member5" />
                <Member id= "6" name="Member6" />
                <Member id= "7" name="Member7" />
                <Member id= "9" name="Member9" />
                <Member id= "10" name="Member10" />
                <Member id= "11" name="Member11" />
                <Member id= "12" name="Member12" />
                <Member id= "13" name="Member13" />
                <Member id= "16" name="Member16" />
                <Member id= "17" name="Member17" />
                <Member id= "18" name="Member18" />
                <Member id= "19" name="Member19" />
            </Dimension>
        </Pattern>
        <Pattern id="P2" name="Pattern2">
            <Dimension name="Dim1">
                <Member id= "1" name="Member1" />
                <Member id= "2" name="Member2" />
                <Member id= "3" name="Member3" />
                <Member id= "4" name="Member4" />
                <Member id= "5" name="Member5" />
                <Member id= "6" name="Member6" />
                <Member id= "8" name="Member8" />
                <Member id= "11" name="Member11" />
                <Member id= "12" name="Member12" />
                <Member id= "13" name="Member13" />
                <Member id= "14" name="Member14" />
                <Member id= "15" name="Member15" />
                <Member id= "16" name="Member16" />
                <Member id= "17" name="Member17" />
            </Dimension>
        </Pattern>
    </Param>
    <Dimension name="Dim1">
        <Member id= "1" name="Member1" >
            <Member id= "2" name="Member2" >
                <Member id= "3" name="Member3" />
                <Member id= "4" name="Member4" />
                <Member id= "5" name="Member5" />
                <Member id= "6" name="Member6" />
                <Member id= "7" name="Member7" />
            </Member>
            <Member id= "8" name="Member8" >
                <Member id= "9" name="Member9" />
                <Member id= "10" name="Member10" />
                <Member id= "11" name="Member11" />
            </Member>
            <Member id= "12" name="Member12" >
                <Member id= "13" name="Member13" />
                <Member id= "14" name="Member14" />
                <Member id= "15" name="Member15" />
                <Member id= "16" name="Member16" />
                <Member id= "17" name="Member17" />
                <Member id= "18" name="Member18" />
                <Member id= "19" name="Member19" />
                <Member id= "20" name="Member20" />
            </Member>
        </Member>
    </Dimension>
</Root>
```

members from Pattern/Dimension/Member has to be compared to root Dimension element and in the out put the difference is required like below.

```
<Root>  
    <Pattern id="P1" name="Pattern1">
        <Dimension name="Dim1">
            <Member id= "2" name="Member2" />
            <Member id= "3" name="Member3" />
            <Member id= "8" name="Member8" />
            <Member id= "14" name="Member14" />
            <Member id= "15" name="Member15" />
            <Member id= "20" name="Member20" />
        </Dimension>
    </Pattern>
    <Pattern id="P2" name="Pattern2">
        <Dimension name="Dim1">
            <Member id= "7" name="Member7" />
            <Member id= "9" name="Member9" />
            <Member id= "10" name="Member10" />
            <Member id= "18" name="Member18" />
            <Member id= "19" name="Member19" />
            <Member id= "20" name="Member20" />
        </Dimension>
    </Pattern>
</Root>
```

for Pattern1, 
when compared to /Root/Dimension//Members, the below difference found in the sample example

Member2
Member3
Member8
Member14
Member15
Member20

same logic for different pattern. is it possible to achieve by XSLT 1.0? Can any one please help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly start off with the identity template...

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, from looking at your requirements, you only want `Param/Pattern` elements in your output, so you can start off by selecting them...

```
<xsl:template match="Root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Param/Pattern"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

`Pattern` elements themselves are unchanged, so will be handled by the identity template, but for the child `Dimension` elements you want to select `Member` elements from the `Root\Dimension` element that do not correspond to the current `Dimension`, so the template would look like this

```
<xsl:template match="Pattern/Dimension">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/Root/Dimension//Member[not(@id = current()/Member/@id)]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You would also need a template to stop the whole hieracrhical structure of the `Member` element being copied, and only copy the parent one.

```
<xsl:template match="Member">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="Root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Param/Pattern"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Pattern/Dimension">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/Root/Dimension//Member[not(@id = current()/Member/@id)]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Member">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, One more help from the above. Can you please explain me how to get only Parent node from the above answer. Like in the output, need to skip Member 3 as it is the child member for member 2 `code`<Dimension name="Dim1">
            <Member id= "2" name="Member2" />
            <Member id= "8" name="Member8" />
            <Member id= "14" name="Member14" />
            <Member id= "15" name="Member15" />
            <Member id= "20" name="Member20" />
        </Dimension>`code`

Comment: It is probably best you ask a whole new separate question, as it is very hard to read code in comments. Thanks